# Searching Elastic Search for a specific index position of an array field

Tags: elasticsearch

The records in my ES index are of the form:

```
person: {
    firstName: "ABC",
    lastName: "Def",
    specialValues: [3, 6, null, 9]
}
```

I want to retrieve all `person.speciaValues[1]` that have a value 6.
Is is possible to do so, using Elastic Search?